# Out of Range error Copying UsedRange - Why did this break?

Tags: excel, vba

(I know the code is messy - I'll refactor when it works)

This code chucks up an 'Out of Range' error. **It worked for days**, and then suddenly stopped working and I can't figure out why.

The desired functionality is:

1. File dialog and open Excel file.
2. Open the workbook
3. Copy data in first sheet to clipboard
4. Paste into A1 on pre-existing sheet in ThisWorkbook
5. Close workbook

Debugging suggests it's OpenBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy which is failing.

I think I must have knocked something while editing at the bottom of the Sub?

Thanks in advance :)

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
    
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    
    'Stops screen flicker as focus changes
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Opens file dialogue and saves filename to FileToOpen
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Choose the data you want to analyse.", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")

    'If a file is chosen, do this...
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        'Ensure sheet is empty before pasting new values
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells.Clear
        
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        
        
        'THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy
        

        'Pastes into the A1 cell
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, 1) <> "Organisation and Cost Centre" Then
            'Deletes the first two rows of the report which are file info only
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Rows("1:2").Delete
        End If
        'Change focus back to the Import Data sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import Data").Activate
        'Close the source file
        OpenBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
    'Turn updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Sheets(1)` a worksheet? Try using `Worksheets(1)` because `Sheets` contains all type of sheets like chart sheets, worksheets etc. but `Worksheets` only contains worksheets and that is what you need because a chart sheet does not have ranges.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried that, but it also doesn't work. I am opening a known export from Oracle, so I can be sure it's Sheet(1) I want and that it is a worksheet.

Comment: What is `Debug.Print OpenBook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Address` in case of the error?

Comment: did you use it in the same place where `OpenBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy` was? because that errors looks odd to me now.

Comment: The address of the UsedRange returns as $A$1:$AD$1371 which is correct.

Comment: Well then `OpenBook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy` should work too. I'll post an answer with an alternative way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following alternative instead of using `.Copy`

```
Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)

With OpenBook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    'Pastes into the A1 cell
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
End With

If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, 1) <> "Organisation and Cost Centre" Then
    'Deletes the first two rows of the report which are file info only
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Rows("1:2").Delete
End If
```

Comment: I got it working. Honestly, I think it might have been the name of a worksheet further down and a combination of VBA's cryptic debugging and my ineptitude.

I genuinely appreciated your time, Pᴇʜ. Thank you!